# R-forecast_package Arima (seasonal) equivalent in Python stasmodels

Tags: python, r, time-series, forecast

I just became aware that the Arima function in R forecast package has this parameter lambda and biasadj. I'll like to know where can i find something similar in Python. I looked at statsmodels (which is the package i am using to forecast my time series) arima function, but i am not aware of those parameters (which i need).

I'll appreciate any guidence.

[image]

Comment: FYI, with the way you've written this question/title, there is a risk that others will close it as "seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more." I suggest rewriting to include your `statsmodels` command and asking how to add a box-cox transform (either to `statsmodels.tsa.arima` or some other python function).